# "host/network not found", trying to restrict OUTPUT traffic with ferm

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall

I'm trying to block all output traffic from a server, allowing just a few domains to be reached through HTTP/HTTPS.

When I restart `ferm` with the following configuration (I removed INPUT and FORWARD chains as they're not relevant), I get a `iptables v1.6.1: host/network 'serverfault.com' not found` error:

```
table filter {
  chain OUTPUT {
    policy DROP;

    # allow ICMP protocol
    protocol icmp ACCEPT;

    # allow DNS lookup
    protocol (tcp udp) dport 53 ACCEPT;

    protocol tcp dport (http https) {
      daddr serverfault.com ACCEPT; 
    }

    # connection tracking
    mod conntrack ctstate INVALID DROP;
    mod conntrack ctstate (ESTABLISHED RELATED) ACCEPT;
  }
}
```

I allowed port 53 for DNS lookup, and it seems I can reach this domain (wasn't allowed to run the `host` command before to do so). Am I missing something that I should allow in my firewall?

```sh
$ host serverfault.com
serverfault.com has address 151.101.193.69
serverfault.com has address 151.101.129.69
serverfault.com has address 151.101.65.69
serverfault.com has address 151.101.1.69
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use IP addresses in IPTables rules, you cannot use DNS names.

Comment: Thanks, it works with the IP (and it makes sense to not use the domaine in terms of security). [ferm documentation](http://ferm.foo-projects.org/download/2.5/ferm.html) shows an exemple with a domain (`daddr my.domain.com ACCEPT;`), I'd be curious to know how that'd be possible, if possible.

Comment: Actually domain names seem to work with `iptables`. However, the problem is that `iptables` resolves domain name to an IP address when you add the rule. If the IP address for domain name changes after adding rule, the rule won't work. Additionally, IPTables might not resolve all IP addresses for domain when adding the rule. The error message you see is most likely caused by incorrect name server setup on the server.